# Set a named range based on search result Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, search, range

I’m cleaning up some data that I have to clean up on a regular basis. Manual process driving me nuts.
I would like to set a range name, based on a search in a single column for two values. I'm using Excel 2007 if that assists.

I have read many threads but cannot find anything this specific. The closest thread was Excel VBA - Making a Named Range based on a found cell

For example Search column A and when you find the word department set that as the beginning of a range then continue to search column A and when you find the word Medium set that as the second point in the range. 
So the search has located Department at A5 and Medium at A24 I now want to set that range (“A5:A24”) and give it a name. Any name will do Just need to see how it’s done?
Once I can do this I can work out other things I do with these found ranges such as delete them, Mark them, Copy them etcetera. The main point is defining them in the fist place.

I can do the search to find both and have been performing some loops to do the same but I have no clue in how to set the range based on that search result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQN42.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to create a `Range` from two found cells in a column, using the row number of each and the column number in question.

This can be modified to handle cells in differing columns, depending on your use case. You can delete, mark, and copy `combinedRng` without having to name it.

```
Sub MakeMyRange()
    Dim departmentRng As Range, mediumRng As Range

    With ActiveSheet.Columns(1)
        Set departmentRng = .Find("Department")
        Set mediumRng = .Find("Medium")
    End With

    If Not departmentRng Is Nothing Then
        If Not mediumRng Is Nothing Then
            Dim combinedRng As Range
            Set combinedRng = Range(Cells(departmentRng.Row, 1), Cells(mediumRng.Row, 1))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

If you really need to name the range, you could just do:

```
combinedRng.Name = "Test"
```

Comment: Hey Big Ben. Thanks for the response. I run the script but it does not appear to do anything. Pretty sure that's my fault I failed to mention I'm still using Excel 2007 (My bad) Would this affect the running of the code? I have only just had a few goes at it. So give me a day and If I cannot nut it out Ill come back and ask for help. Thank you again.

Comment: Excel 2007 shouldn't affect anything. It sounds like one or both of the terms "Department" and "Medium" is not being found.

Comment: Hey Ben. Yes it does seem to be finding those as it is filling the variables when I point at them scrolling using F8. How do I get it to select the range or name it.? The following code is what I have been using but the length changes and I have to modify it each time I run it.   Sub Makerange()

' RUN   SIXTH  WORKS WORKS WORKS


Range("A1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Department"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

ActiveCell.Select

ActiveCell.Resize(18, 1).Select

Selection.Name = "DepartmentA"

Loop

End Sub

Comment: If you want to select, add a `combinedRng.Select` after the `Set combinedRng = ...` line.

Comment: @BigBen why you dont mix both if not together?